# Portar código C++ a C

Tags: c++, c, migration

Necesito cambiar este código que esta en C++ a C, pero me salen unos errores que no entiendo.

El programa de C++ esta perfecto; compila sin problemas.

El error `unknown type name 'treenodo'` la verdad no se que quiera decir.

```
using namespace std;                                
//Programa que crea los nodos de un árbol binario en memoria.
struct treenodo {
   struct treenodo *izqptr;         //puntero al nodo izquierdo
   int dato;                //dato del nodo
   struct treenodo *derptr; };      // puntero al nodo derecho

void crear(treenodo *nodo)      //crea un  Árbol binario
{
char resp[1];
system("cls");
cout<< "Entre el dato: ";
 cin>>nodo->dato;
cout <<"Hay nodos a la Izquierda de " << nodo -> dato << " entre S/N ";
cin>>resp;
if (strcmp(resp, "S") == 0 || strcmp(resp, "s") == 0){
    nodo->izqptr= new (treenodo);
    crear(nodo->izqptr); }
else
    nodo->izqptr=NULL;
cout <<"Hay nodos a la Derecha de " << nodo -> dato << " entre S/N ";
cin>>resp;
if (strcmp(resp, "S") == 0 || strcmp(resp, "s") == 0){
       nodo->derptr = new (treenodo);
       crear(nodo->derptr); }
else
       nodo->derptr= NULL;
return;
}


main(){
    treenodo *nodo;   // puntero al nodo
    nodo= new treenodo;
    crear (nodo);
    system("cls");
    cout <<"\t\t\t\t  ---Arbol Binario Creado en memoria ---"<<endl;
getch();
}
```

El error:

[image: ERROR QUE ME SALE]

Comment: En C++, cuando creas una estructura `treenodo` automáticamente tienes un nuevo tipo de datos llamado `treenodo`. En C esto no es exactamente así. El nuevo tipo creado se llama `struct treenodo` (es decir, necesita la palabra `struct` delante). Por eso a menudo se ve el truco de `typedef struct treenodo treenodo` para definir un tipo llamado `treenodo` como equivalente a `struct treenodo` evitando así tener que poner `struct` delante.

Answer (score 0):

no si sepas pero al principio de tu codigo esta el using namespace std, esta no es una funcion de c, en de c++.Me imagino que por esto te sale error.

Tambien nesesitas eliminar tus "cout" y remplazarlos por "printf("")".
Al igual que "cin" por (en mi opinion) "scanf("")".